# How to apply the ratio of document.height / window.height on a scale from 1 to 100.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make scroll bar using two divs with heights of 110px and 10px. The smaller one is inside the tallest one. That gives me room to change the margin-height of the smaller one from 0 to 100px and it will still fit inside the taller one.

In case you wonder, the 0 to 100px is what I meant on the question title by fitting on a scale from 1 to a 100.

What I want to do now, is to figure out how to calculate the ratio to make my 10px height position in relation to the taller div proportional to the document.height ratio to the window.height.

I've been experimenting all night long but haven't got anything functional. Here is some of the code that I have, but I'm erasing all related to what I'm questioning here because I want to hear pure ideas.

Please advice.

```
var wheight = $(window).height();
var dheight = $(document).height();
document.getElementById("wheight").innerHTML=wheight;
document.getElementById("dheight").innerHTML=dheight;
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").style.marginTop = '70px';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/2y63xnxa/4/

Comment: I am not hure I understand your aim... But you could take a look at viewport related units (`vw, vh, vmin, vmax`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: I am not sure either to be honest. I want to make that scroll bar match top and bottom with the document scroll. I learned that the bottom position should be equivalent to document.height - window.height. Still exploring here. Thanks for the link. Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating to a percentage is pretty easy.
Then scaling the percentage up to the size of the scrollbar is trivial.

```
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scrollTop(offset + 20);  
        var wheight = $(window).height();
        var dheight = $(document).height();

        //yep, this is all there is to it.
        var percentualOffset = (offset / wheight) * 100;

        //or use dheight. i'm not sure which applies to you
        //var percentualOffset = (offset / dheight) * 100;

        $("#sidescrollbtn").css("top", percentualOffset);
```

for a working implementation, see http://jsfiddle.net/2y63xnxa/9/

Comment: There are still some other things in your way though.